# Container killed by the ApplicationMaster Exit code is 143 in python script

Tags: hadoop, hive, pyspark, oozie

I have the following error launching a pyspark script using oozie and with a shell.

```
Container killed on request. Exit code is 143
Container exited with a non-zero exit code 143
```

In the script I read and I add a record from/to Hive tables.

I have tried to set more memory but it does not function. Even, I don't believe it is memory because I am just adding one record to Hive table!

```
    spark_conf = SparkConf().setAppName("KB").setAll(settings)
    spark = SparkSession.builder. \
    config(conf = spark_conf). \
    enableHiveSupport(). \
    getOrCreate()


    id=sys.argv[1]     
    importdate = datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")
    query1 = "SELECT * FROM knowledge_blocks.ingestion WHERE id = "+id+""

    ingested = spark.sql(query1)
    title = ingested.select('title').collect()[0]['title']
    content = ingested.select('content').collect()[0]['content']

   ......

    query2 = "INSERT INTO knowledge_blocks.preprocessed PARTITION 
    (creation_date='"+importdate+"') VALUES ('"+str(id)+"', 
    '"+tokens_title+"', 
    '"+tokens_content+"', '"+tokens_content_soft+"')"

    rows = zip([id],[tokens_title],[tokens_content],[tokens_content_soft], 
    [importdate])

    df_spark = spark.createDataFrame(rows, schema=['id','tokens_title','tokens_content','tokens_content_soft','creation_date'])
    df_spark.show()
    df_spark.write.saveAsTable('knowledge_blocks.preprocessed', format='hive', mode='append', partitionBy='creation_date')

     spark.stop()
```

Comment: Looks like you're doing much more than just writing one record. And indeed, error code 143 is often an indication of memory issues. You may want to locate and review the log of a container that was killed.

Comment: I am just writing one record, and I don't understand why it is about memory. If I launch the script from the node, connecting me directly with the file system It is correctly run, however, with the same code in the oozie schedule I have the problem :( Please help !